# Creating a number sequence in excel from the first input number to the second

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to write out numbers in a message box in-between 2 numbers I choose. While checking if they are even numbers and they have to be from the smallest number to the largest. The 2 numbers have to be positive and smaller than 100.

I am using Visual Basic in Excel, but I have never used it before.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim a, b, P, i As Integer

a = InputBox("Write number from 1 to 100 ")
If a <= 0 Or a >= 100 Then
MsgBox "Wrong input"
Exit Sub
End If
b = InputBox("Write number from 1 to 100 ")
If b <= 0 Or b >= 100 Then
MsgBox "Wrong input"
Exit Sub
End If

For i = a To b
If a <> 0 & a <= b Then
a = a + 1
Else
P = a
a = a + 1
Exit For
End If
Next i

MsgBox P


End Sub
```

Comment: I can not figure out how to keep the loop alive after checking if the first number is even.

Comment: Post your code in your original post

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit differently.  You can certainly trigger this with a command_button.  Note that I check for even numbers (and also I would not consider zero to be a positive (or negative, for that matter) number.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateSequence()

   'Note each variable must have a type declaration,
   '   else they will be of type Variant
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim S As String

x = InputBox("First Number")
y = InputBox("Second Number")

If Not CheckNum(x) Or Not CheckNum(y) Then
        MsgBox "Both numbers must be positive and less than 100"
        Exit Sub
    End If

If x > y Then 'reverse x and y
    z = y
    y = x
    x = z
End If

For z = x To y
    'check if even and add to string if they are
    If z Mod 2 = 0 Then S = S & vbLf & z
Next z

'Remove the leading separator (vbLf)
S = Mid(S, 2)

MsgBox S

End Sub

Function CheckNum(L As Long) As Boolean
    If L > 0 And L < 100 Then
        CheckNum = True
    Else
        CheckNum = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: That is a bit to complicated for me, I have no idea what you did with Check Num . And I do not know what vbLf is.

Comment: It is pretty good but I need the resulting numbers to be displayed in a row, not a column and I also need to know how to do the sequencing from the last number to the first

Comment: @MarkoPlavanjac If you step through the code, and examine the variables in the immediate window, you should be able to figure all that out.  `vbLf` is the linefeed character; so if you want to use a different delimiter, merely change that.  If you want to sequence from the last number to the first, which is opposite from what you asked, you would just use the `Step` argument of the `For ... Next` statement with a negative value.   **Is this homework?**

Comment: @MarkoPlavanjac  You might want to do an internet search regarding use of the `For ... Next` statement in VBA